# 2+2=square root of 16. What's the appropriate answer?

Tags: complex-numbers, arithmetic

4? Positive and negative 4?

I just got into an argument with a buddy about this. He argues if it's not an i, it's not included as a imaginary number, but only the real positive number.

Comment: $2+2=4$, I see no argument whatsoever. Btw, what has this to do with linear algebra?

Comment: Is the question (1) whether it's true that $2+2=\sqrt{16}$, or (2) what all of the square roots of $16$ are, both real and complex?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How $\sqrt{x}$ is an function?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033604/how-sqrtx-is-an-function)

Answer (score 4):

Both numbers when squared make $16$...
$$\left(4\right)^2 = 16,\ \ (-4)^2 = (-1)^2(4)^2 = 1\cdot (4^2) = 16$$

By convention, if $x>0$ we typically allow $\sqrt x$ to represent the positive of the two solutions, and denote $\pm\sqrt{x}$ to consider both solutions.

If you are concerned about imaginary numbers, these only appear for square roots of negative numbers. I.E. $\sqrt {-16} = \pm 4i$. This is true for the following reason:
$$\left(-4i\right)^2 = (-1)^2i^24^2 = (1)(-1)(16) = -16 = (i^2)(16) = (4i)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

The square root of 16 can either be 4 or -4. However, we usually take the positive square root by default, so it's just 4. Imaginary numbers come into play only when talking about 'square roots' of negative numbers. $2+2=4$ is, I think, accepted in general, but the square root issue is a separate question.