# What is the domain and range of $y = \sqrt{9 − x^2}$?

Tags: functions

What is the domain and range of real function $f(x) = \sqrt{9 − x^2}$?

In order to find the function's domain, you need to take into account the fact that, for real numbers, you can only take the square root of a positive number.  In other words, in order for the function to be defined, you need the expression that's under the square root to be positive.
\begin{align*}
9−x^2 & \geq 0\\
x^2 & \leq 9\\
|x| & \leq 3
\end{align*}
This means that you have $x \geq −3$ and $x \leq 3$.

Therefore, the domain of the function will be $x \in [−3,3]$.

But what will be the range?

Help appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried drawing a graph?

Comment: **Hint:** $y=\sqrt{9-x^2}\implies x^2+y^2=9$.

Comment: so is this a circle with radius 3 ?

Comment: Not quite.  Notice that $f(x)$ can't be negative.

Comment: So the range will be [-3,3]  why cant f(x) be negative?

Comment: No, the graph of $x^2+ y^2= 9$ is a circle.  For your original function, $y= \sqrt{9- x^2}$, y is non-negative.  Its graph is the upper half of that circle.

Comment: Clearly $y\geq 0$. Now we find whether the function is increasing or decreasing by finding first derivative and second derivative $y^{\prime},y^{\prime \prime}$. Clearly $y^{\prime \prime} \geq 0$, hence the function is decreasing. Function attains maximum value at $x=0$ and minimum at $x=3,-3$. Hence the range is $[0,3]$

Comment: $f(x)$ can't be negative because you can only take the square root of nonnegative numbers, and the square root of a nonnegative number is nonnegative.  To convince yourself of that try to find an $x$ in $[-3,3]$ (or in fact in any domain) such that $f(x) = -3$.

Comment: Ok Shahid @x = 0 is'nt the function going to SQRT(9) = +3 or -3 why [0,3] ?

Comment: Then this will be relation not function! If you define relation as function then we take only principal root.

Comment: Why are we taking principal root here? why not consider the -ve 3 this is not clear

Comment: No: $\sqrt{9}=3$, not $-3$ (in high school at least).  See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448885/square-root-confusion/1448892#1448892).

Comment: Ok what about above high school in that case will this be range= [-3,3]

Comment: You can define $\sqrt{}$ as a *relation* rather than a function -- meaning it can take multiple values for a single input.  But even beyond high school this is not very desirable most of the time.  So for real numbers at least, defining $\sqrt{}$ as a *function* by having it return only the principal (meaning nonnegative) square root is the usual convention.

Comment: If you're convinced that your teacher defines $\sqrt{}$ as a multivalued relation, then you're right: the range will be $[-3,3]$.  But I think that is unlikely. -- Especially since the notation $f(x)$ is almost exclusively used for *functions*, not *relations*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual convention is that the principal square root function $f(x) = \sqrt x$ returns only the non-negative root. So in this case, the range corresponds to the semicircular upper half of the circle defined by $x^2 + y^2 = 9$. Which gives the range as $[0,3]$.

Comment: You are saying usual convention... where is that convention written? This statement below is not really correct 

_The usual convention is that the square root function f(x)=x√f(x)=x returns only the non-negative root_

Comment: $y = \sqrt{x}$ means the [principal square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root).  See my response to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033604/why-is-sqrtx-a-function/1033616#1033616) about why $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is a function.

Comment: @Cyril Added the word "principal" for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Since a square is non-negative, $0\le 9-x^2\le9\;$ on $\;[-3,3]$, and $\;\sqrt x\;$ is a continuous increasing function.

Answer (score 1):

You correctly found the domain, although you meant that the expression that's under the square root, which is called the [radicand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root), must be non-negative.

Observe that $y = \sqrt{9 - x^2} \implies y \geq 0$.  Moreover, if we square both sides of the equation, we obtain $y^2 = 9 - x^2$, which is equivalent to 
$$x^2 + y^2 = 9$$
This is the equation of a circle with radius $3$ and center at the origin.  The restriction $y \geq 0$ means that we obtain the upper semi-circle, from which you can determine that the range is $[0, 3]$.

[image: upper_semi-circle]

**Addendum:**  I gather from the comments that you have left that you were not aware that the notation $y = \sqrt{x}$ means the [principal (non-negative) square root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033604/why-is-sqrtx-a-function/1033616#1033616) of $x$.  That is what allows us to conclude that $y \geq 0$.

Comment: appreciate your effort! Unfortunately i could accept only one answer.. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

$$9-x^2\ge 0\implies D_f=[-3,3]$$
set $x=3\sin\theta$
$$y=\sqrt{9-9\sin^2\theta}=3\,|\,\cos\theta\,|\implies R_f=[0,3]$$

Answer (score 1):

You just need to find the absolute maxima or minima of $f(x)$ in its domain $[-3,3]$. Write $f(x)=√g(x)$, where $g(x)=9-x^2$. Now, $g(x)$ has an extrema if $g'(x)=0$ which gives $x=0$ as the point of maxima as $g''(0)<0$. Hence $f(0)=√g(0)=3$, $f(-3)=f(3)=0$. Clearly, $Range(f)=[0,3]$.