# find the equation of the tangent line to the curve $y = {\sqrt{x+2}}$ at the point where $ x=2$

Tags: calculus, limits

The question asks for the equation of the tangent line.

So I need this formula $$y-y_1 =m(x-x_1)$$

and the concept of derivatives

$$\lim_{Δ x\to 0} \frac{f(x+Δx) - f(x)}{Δx}$$

Ok, now I have that, I need to find $f(2)$. Let's proceed.

$$f(2) = {\sqrt{2+2}} = 2$$

Wait, But $\sqrt{4}$ also has $-2$ as a root, what should I do? go on with $2$ or with $-2$?

I intended to find the slope and then plug it in  the formula with the point $(2,2)$ to find the equation. If someone can solve this question I'll be grateful.

Comment: $\sqrt{x}$ is only the positive root. It is also called the principal root. So it would be 2.

Comment: Not necessarily. The best thing to do is ask the person who posed the question what exactly they meant.

Comment: @Nick No, not really. $\sqrt x$ does imply the positive root only.

Comment: For the reason why we choose the positive root, see [Why is $\sqrt{x}$ a function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033604/why-is-sqrtx-a-function)

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Great, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$y'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+2}}\to m=y'(2)=\frac{1}{4}$$

and $(x_1,y_1)=(2,f(2))=(2,2)$.

Ps.: By definition, $\sqrt{4}=2$, and more general, if we have $a>0$ then $\sqrt{a}>0.$

Can you finish?

Comment: Yes I had found this result, But I didn't understand why You choose 2 instead of -2.

Comment: @hjx: because, by definition, $\sqrt{4}=2$

Comment: Ok then, Valeu Arnaldo.