# Modulus and square root

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

How is this statement true?
"For any real number $x$ we have $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$"?
Because putting $x=2$
$\sqrt{x^2}$ gives BOTH $2$ and $-2$
But $|x|$ only gives $2$

Comment: Indeed $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$,can be confuse as you said.... As convention, the square root function is only the positive part, so the statement is true.

Comment: Do you mean that by convention, √4 is only 2 and not -2?

Comment: Square root a number always gives a positive answer.

Comment: By convention, the square root function always gives a positive number, though both signs are valid. Hence $\sqrt{x}>0$ always.

Comment: Your assertion that $\sqrt{4} = \pm 2$ is false.  If $x$ is a real number, the notation $\sqrt{x}$ means the [principal (nonnegative) square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root) of $x$.  Also, see this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033604/why-is-sqrtx-a-function).

Answer (score 3):

Remember that by definition and for $x \in \mathbb{R}$
$$|x| = \begin{cases} x, & \mbox{if }  x \ge 0  \\ -x,  & \mbox{if } x < 0. \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let a number $n \in \mathbb{R}$, Then
$$\sqrt{n} \geq 0.$$

Comment: What if $n \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: What if $n\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n<0$ ...?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the square root of $y\ge 0$ is the $x\ge 0$ such that $x^2=y$, not only the $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2=y$.

For example:

$$\sqrt{3^2}=\sqrt{9}=3=|3|,$$

but

$$\sqrt{(-3)^2}=\sqrt{9}=3=|-3|.$$