# Find the range of the function $y = \sqrt{7 - x^2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried to find the range of the following function : $$y=\sqrt{7-x^2}$$
I found the domain which is: $$ y \in (-\sqrt7,\sqrt7) $$
and then I tried to find the range of the function with the method of finding the domain of its inverse function. So : $$y=\sqrt{7-x^2} \Rightarrow $$ $$y^2=7-x^2\Rightarrow$$ $$x^2=7-y^2\Rightarrow$$
$$x=\sqrt{7-y^2} $$
Domain of which is 
$$ x \in (-\sqrt7,\sqrt7) $$ But the correct solution is: $$ x \in (0,\sqrt7) $$
Can someone explain where is the mistake?

Comment: The notation $\sqrt{x}$ means the [principal (nonegative) square root of $x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033604/why-is-sqrtx-a-function/1033616#1033616).

Answer (score 1):

Since domain of $y$ is $x \in [-\sqrt7 , \sqrt7]$, then range of $y$ is $y \in [0,\sqrt7]$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sqrt{7-x^2}$ can never be negative this excludes all the values $(-\sqrt{7},0)$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have displaced the concept of domain and range. The domain actually constrains the independent variable which is $x$ here. So the domain is $$x\in[-\sqrt 7,\sqrt 7]$$and the range consecutively becomes $$y\in[0,\sqrt 7]$$

Answer (score 0):

First, a tidbit about notation. The domain variable is $x,$ not $y,$ and vice versa. As for the range, recall that if $$y=\sqrt{7-x^2},$$ then since RHS is never negative, it follows that $$0\le y.$$ Combine this with the your calculation that $|y|\le\sqrt 7,$ and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

The image of the function described by $y = \sqrt{7 - x^{2}}$ is the upper semicircle centered at the origin with radius $\sqrt{7}$. Thus its range is given by the set $[0,\sqrt{7}]$.

Answer (score 0):

The implicit domain of the function $y = \sqrt{7 - x^2}$ is the set of all real numbers $x$ such that $7 - x^2 \geq 0$.
\begin{align*}
7 - x^2 & \geq 0\\
7 & \geq x^2\\
\sqrt{7} & \geq |x|
\end{align*}
Hence, $-\sqrt{7} \leq x \leq 7$, so the domain of the function is $[-\sqrt{7}, \sqrt{7}]$.  Notice that the endpoints are included.

The notation $y = \sqrt{x}$ denotes the [principal (nonnegative) square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root) of $x$.

Therefore, $y = \sqrt{7 - x^2} \geq 0$ for each $x$ in its domain.  In particular, equality holds if $x = \pm \sqrt{7}$.  Moreover, $y = \sqrt{7 - x^2}$ is at most $\sqrt{7}$, which occurs when $x = 0$. Since $y = \sqrt{7 - x^2}$ is continuous on its domain, $y$ assumes every value in the closed interval $[0, \sqrt{7}]$ by the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem). Hence, the range of the function is $[0, \sqrt{7}]$. Again, notice that the endpoints are included.