# Square-root function

Tags: functions

Recently, I was learning about square-root function which has domain [0,∞) and range is [0,∞).

I understand that domain has to be positive numbers but why range is restricted to positive numbers?

Comment: See [Square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Properties_and_uses): "Square roots of negative numbers can be discussed within the framework of complex numbers. "

Comment: Welcome to MSE. The set $[0,\infty)$ is *not* the set of positive integers.

Comment: The interval $[0, \infty)$ is the set of all nonnegative *real* numbers.

Comment: they might be talking about real number and not the complex number.

Comment: You seem to be asking about why we take only the principal square root of nonnegative real numbers.  See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033604/why-is-sqrtx-a-function/1033616#1033616).

Comment: Sorry, everyone. I wrote "integers" in place of "numbers".

Answer (score 0):

[Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) typically return a single output for each input.

For nonnegative $x,$ the $n^\text{th}$ root *function* of $x$ is defined as **the principal** (nonnegative) **$n^\text{th}$ root** of $x,$ i.e., $$\sqrt[n] {x^n}=|x|.$$

So, while $4$ has two square roots $(-2$ and $2),$ and seven $7^\text{th}$ roots, and so on, the square root function returns only a single value $2$ when the input is $4:$ $$\sqrt4=2\neq\pm2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we would consider that while solving some equations like $x^{2}=4$, the solution looks like $x=±2$.

The functions that we learned in high school, however, were almost a single input and an output(That's how we defined a function). Thus these redundancies are required to delete.

Similarly, for some functions like $f(x) = arcsin(x)$ and $f(x)=sin(x)$, we draw them in the same way but a 90° rotation for $arcsin(x)$. Since we already have a 'One input one output' in mind, by deleting the redundancy, only left a codomain of $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).